# What are the ZeroMQ valid .recv() flags?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

[In `pyzmq` `Socket.recv_pyobj`](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/192d0ea1e9e4c3c688d17a6901c5bb895f24a7e1/zmq/sugar/socket.py), you can supply an optional parameter `int flags`, which can be 'Any valid **`.recv()`** flag'. Unfortunately I can't find any reference as to what these flags actually are.

**So, what are the valid `.recv()` flags in ZeroMQ?**

I've tagged this question with both the `pyzmq` and `zeromq` tags because I believe the answer may not be specific to `pyzmq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ZeroMQ v.2.x **`.recv()`** method supports **`ZMQ_NOBLOCK`** flag and **`ZMQ_RCVMORE`** flag.

The **`flags`** argument, as defined in the API, is a combination of the flags.

Be also informed, that respective third party language bindings / wrappers  { may | do } provide their respective own ( typically **`#define`**'d constant names ), so the best place to check is the `pyzmq` source code.

So far a python was equipped with these flag-constants in this manner:

```
import zmq

print( zmq.__version__ )
2.1.11

print( zmq.NOBLOCK )
1

print( zmq.RCVMORE )
13

print( zmq.Socket.recv.__doc__ )
...
```